# Compose BottomSheetScaffold blocks child touch event when multiple touch

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

[image]

I have a problem with a bottomsheetscaffold.
It's horizontal view and MapView on back, bottomsheet on front like the picture.

The behavior is simple. The Map interacts for the user touch.

when single touch a place on the map, the bottomsheet shows up on the left-bottom side of screen. When bottomsheet shows, it also can be expanded to top of screen by dragging.

I'm using BottomSheetScaffold, so basically the Red is a BottomSheetScaffold area and the Green is a SheetContentArea.

when i do pinch-zoom on Map area, no problem. The map can be zoom-in or zoom out correctly.
And when i do pinch-zoom inside the red area the result is also correct because of `pointerInteropFilter`.

The problem is, when i do pinch-zoome one finger on the read area, and another one on the map area, nothing's happened. In this case, the map doesn't interact for the touch at all. Single tab, gesture, click.. nothing is triggered on the MapView. Only the bottom sheet accepts the touch event.

My screen has 3 composables : mapview, navHost, bottomsheet
Here's my code.

```
AndroidView(
   modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
   factory = { mapView }
)

// This uses NavHost from navigation-compose
MainNavigation(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
        .pointerInteropFilter(
             requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent = 
                   RequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent().apply {
                            invoke(false)
                   },
             onTouchEvent = { false }
         )
  ...
)

val rotationState = viewModel.rotationState.observeAsState().value ?: MainBottomSheetViewModel.RotationState()
val uiState = viewModel.uiState.observeAsState().value ?: MainBottomSheetViewModel.BottomSheetUiState.Hide

MainBottomSheetScaffold(
    modifier = Modifier
        .width(360.dp)
        .height(rotationState.width)
        .pointerInteropFilter(
             requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent = 
                   RequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent().apply {
                            invoke(false)
                   },
             onTouchEvent = { false }
         ),
    sheetContent = { // some composable contents for Green area },
    scaffoldState = viewModel.sheetState,
    sheetPeekHeight = viewModel.peekHeight.dp,
    sheetGesturesEnabled = viewModel.gestureEnable,
) {}
```

When the problem happened, onTouchEvent of bottomsheetscaffold is triggered.
Even if It returns false, the mapview's is not triggered.

I tried to add pointerInteropFilter to mapview, the problem still happened.
Does any one know how to solve this?

Comment: Did you find a solution?  I am wondering the same.

Answer (score 0):

As possible quickfix I can propose to copypaste internal sourcecode of `androidx.compose.material.BottomSheetScaffold` and remove `Surface` from `body` param of `BottomSheetScaffoldStack`. Looks smth like this:

```
BottomSheetScaffoldStack(
    body = {
        Column(Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
            topBar?.invoke()
            content(PaddingValues(bottom = sheetPeekHeight))
        }
    }, 
    ... 
}
```

Surface just intercept touch events, and it's not needed anymore to have it at all in yours case

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the issue will be fixed sometime in the future: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/275407797. But for now you can use the following workaround. First create this modifier:

```kotlin
fun Modifier.ignoreNextModifiers(): Modifier {
    return object : Modifier by this {

        override fun then(other: Modifier): Modifier {
            return this
        }
    }
}
```

Then pass it to your `BottomSheetScaffold`:

```kotlin
BottomSheetScaffold(
    modifier = Modifier
        .width(360.dp)
        .height(rotationState.width)
        .ignoreNextModifiers(),
    sheetContent = { // some composable contents for Green area },
    scaffoldState = viewModel.sheetState,
    sheetPeekHeight = viewModel.peekHeight.dp,
    sheetGesturesEnabled = viewModel.gestureEnable,
) {}
```

This way the modifiers that `BottomSheetScaffold` adds will be ignored, including the one that blocks touch propagation to the views behind it.